# Expect tool not matching line breaks without using wildcards

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, expect

I'm writing a script to remotely install linux software updates (which use a .bin updater tool) using Expect. I'm having trouble matching one block, and I've tried a bunch of variations with no success. I've gotten other similar scripts to work, but I've used wildcards to match newlines, and in this case, I need to make sure the list of files is exactly what I'm expecting, so I didn't want to break it up with any wildcards that could hide a mismatch.

Can someone take a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**Console output, plain**

```
Checking for local modifications.

List of modifications made within Jira directories.

The following provides a list of file modifications within the
atlassian-jira directory.

Modified files:
    atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/seraph-config.xml
    bin/setenv.sh
    conf/server.xml
Removed files:
    (none)
Added files:
    atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/crowd.properties

[Enter]
```

**My latest attempt to match it and send Enter (line breaks only added to Stack Overflow, not present in script**

> `expect {*Checking for local modifications*Modified files:\r\n\tatlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/seraph-config.xml\r\n\tbin/setenv.sh\r\n\tconf/server.xml\r\nRemoved files:\r\n\t(none)\r\nAdded files:\r\n\tatlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/crowd.properties\r\n\r\n\[Enter\]}`

When I run through `expect` with the `-d` flag, this is what it prints:

> `expect: does "\r\nn\r\n\r\nChecking for local modifications.\r\n\r\nList of modifications made within Jira directories.\r\n\r\nThe following provides a list of file modifications within the\r\natlassian-jira directory.\r\n\r\nModified files:\r\n\tatlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/seraph-config.xml\r\n\tbin/setenv.sh\r\n\tconf/server.xml\r\nRemoved files:\r\n\t(none)\r\nAdded files:\r\n\tatlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/crowd.properties\r\n\r\n[Enter]\r\n" (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "*Checking for local modifications*Modified files:\r\n\tatlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/seraph-config.xml\r\n\tbin/setenv.sh\r\n\tconf/server.xml\r\nRemoved files:\r\n\t(none)\r\nAdded files:\r\n\tatlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/crowd.properties\r\n\r\n\[Enter\]"? no`

I'm running from an outer bash script like so:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

sudo expect -d << EOD
    spawn ${INSTALLER_PATH}

    expect_before timeout { exit 1 }

    expect {Match phrase} {
        send -- "\r"
    }

    ...

    expect eof

EOD
```

** ***Update 4/5/2021*** **

I tried @pynexj's suggestion to use `""` instead of `{}` to surround my expression (below), it still doesn't work.

**New script**

```bash
sudo expect -d << EOD
    ...
    expect "\r\nn\r\n\r\nChecking for local modifications.\r\n\r\nList of modifications made within Jira directories.\r\n\r\nThe following provides a list of file modifications within the\r\natlassian-jira directory.\r\n\r\nModified files:\r\n\tatlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/seraph-config.xml\r\n\tbin/setenv.sh\r\n\tconf/server.xml\r\nRemoved files:\r\n\t(none)\r\nAdded files:\r\n\tatlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/crowd.properties\r\n\r\n\[Enter\]\r\n" {
        send -- "\r"
    }

    expect eof

EOD
```

I ran the debug output I received through Beyond Compare and the two strings printed out match each other 100%.

**Updated debug output**

> `expect: does "\r\nn\r\n\r\nChecking for local modifications.\r\n\r\nList of modifications made within Jira directories.\r\n\r\nThe following provides a list of file modifications within the\r\natlassian-jira directory.\r\n\r\nModified files:\r\n\tatlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/seraph-config.xml\r\n\tbin/setenv.sh\r\n\tconf/server.xml\r\nRemoved files:\r\n\t(none)\r\nAdded files:\r\n\tatlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/crowd.properties\r\n\r\n[Enter]\r\n" (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "\r\nn\r\n\r\nChecking for local modifications.\r\n\r\nList of modifications made within Jira directories.\r\n\r\nThe following provides a list of file modifications within the\r\natlassian-jira directory.\r\n\r\nModified files:\r\n\tatlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/seraph-config.xml\r\n\tbin/setenv.sh\r\n\tconf/server.xml\r\nRemoved files:\r\n\t(none)\r\nAdded files:\r\n\tatlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/crowd.properties\r\n\r\n[Enter]\r\n"? no`

**Two strings on top of each other**

You can scroll these sideways in Stack Overflow to see they match 100%:

```
# command output on top
\r\nn\r\n\r\nChecking for local modifications.\r\n\r\nList of modifications made within Jira directories.\r\n\r\nThe following provides a list of file modifications within the\r\natlassian-jira directory.\r\n\r\nModified files:\r\n\tatlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/seraph-config.xml\r\n\tbin/setenv.sh\r\n\tconf/server.xml\r\nRemoved files:\r\n\t(none)\r\nAdded files:\r\n\tatlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/crowd.properties\r\n\r\n[Enter]\r\n
\r\nn\r\n\r\nChecking for local modifications.\r\n\r\nList of modifications made within Jira directories.\r\n\r\nThe following provides a list of file modifications within the\r\natlassian-jira directory.\r\n\r\nModified files:\r\n\tatlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/seraph-config.xml\r\n\tbin/setenv.sh\r\n\tconf/server.xml\r\nRemoved files:\r\n\t(none)\r\nAdded files:\r\n\tatlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/crowd.properties\r\n\r\n[Enter]\r\n
# Expect expression underneath
```

Comment: embedding Expect in shell is messy. take a look at my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/) with which you can write *Expect* all in shell code.

Answer (score 2):

In Tcl, backslash escaped strings (like `\r\n`) embedded in braces (`{}`) has no special meaning. You should use double quotes here.

```
$ tclsh
% puts {foo\tbar\r\n}
foo\tbar\r\n
% puts "foo\tbar\r\n"
foo     bar

%
```

---

According to Tcl [doc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm):

> - **[6] Braces.**
>
>   If the first character of a word is an open brace (`{`) and rule *[5]* does not apply, then the word is terminated by the matching close brace (`}`). Braces nest within the word: for each additional open brace there must be an additional close brace (however, if an open brace or close brace within the word is quoted with a backslash then it is not counted in locating the matching close brace). **No substitutions are performed** on the characters between the braces **except for** backslash-newline substitutions described below, **nor do** semi-colons, newlines, close brackets, or white space receive any special interpretation. The word will consist of **exactly the characters** between the outer braces, **not including** the braces themselves.

But note that when you use double quotes. To match `[Enter]` you need to write `\\\[Enetr\\\]` because by default the `expect` statement uses glob-style matching. For example:

```
$ expect -c 'spawn -noecho bash -c {echo "[Enter]"}; expect eof'
[Enter]
$ expect -c 'spawn -noecho bash -c {echo "[Enter]"}; expect "\\\[Enter\\\]"; expect eof'
[Enter]
$ expect -c 'spawn -noecho bash -c {echo "[Enter]"}; expect -ex "\[Enter\]"; expect eof'
[Enter]
$
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Just noticed you are using Bash's here doc. Then you have to do one more level quoting.

```
$ expect << EOF
> spawn -noecho bash -c {echo "[Enter]"}
> expect "\\\\\\[Enter\\\\\\]"
> expect eof
> EOF
[Enter]
$
```

Or you can use `<< "QUOTED_STRING_HERE"`:

```
$ expect << 'EOF'
> spawn -noecho bash -c {echo "[Enter]"}
> expect "\\\[Enter\\\]"
> expect eof
> EOF
[Enter]
$
```

---

According to `man bash`, for `<< word`:

> **If  any part of word is quoted**, the delimiter is the result of quote
> removal on word, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded.

Comment: Please take a look at my update at the bottom of my question. After trying double quotes, `except` still times out, but its debug output suggests that the strings actually do match.

Comment: @Dov `\[Enter\]` should be `\\\[Enter\\\]`

Comment: When I use `\\\[`, I get this error: **invalid command name "Enter\"
    while executing
"Enter\\"
    invoked from within
"expect "\r\nn\r\n\r\nChecking for local modifications.\r\n\r\nList of modifications made within Jira directories.\r\n\r\nThe following provides a list..."**

Answer (score 0):

I needed to make two changes to get it to match:

1. As [@pynexj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/900078/pynexj) suggested, I needed to surround my expression with `""` instead of `{}`
2. I also needed to pass the -ex argument to the expect command or else it would still not match, even though the debug output indicated character by character that the output matched the expectation

This is what I ended up with, making it as readable as possible:

```bash
sudo expect << EOD
    spawn ${INSTALLER_PATH}

    ...

    expect {*Back up Jira home directory?*Yes \[y\], No \[n, Enter\]} {
        send -- "n\r"
    }

    expect -ex "\r\n\
n\r\n\
\r\n\
Checking for local modifications.\r\n\
\r\n\
List of modifications made within Jira directories.\r\n\
\r\n\
The following provides a list of file modifications within the\r\n\
atlassian-jira directory.\r\n\
\r\n\
Modified files:\r\n\
    atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/seraph-config.xml\r\n\
    bin/setenv.sh\r\n\
    conf/server.xml\r\n\
Removed files:\r\n\
    (none)\r\n\
Added files:\r\n\
    atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/crowd.properties\r\n\
\r\n\
\[Enter\]\r\n\
" {
        send -- "\r"
    }

    expect eof

EOD
```